# Многопоточная работа со связанным списком

Tags: c++, многопоточность, список, mutex

Написал вот такую реализацию двунаправленного связанного списка на C++:

```
class List;

class ListItem {
    public:
        constexpr ListItem(): m_next(nullptr), m_prev(nullptr), m_list(nullptr) {
        }

        ~ListItem() {
            assert(m_list == nullptr);
        }

        bool remove();

        ListItem* next() const {
            return m_next;
        }

        List* list() const {
            return m_list;
        }

        bool inList() const {
            return list() != nullptr;
        }

        bool inList(List* l) const {
            return list() == l;
        }

    private:
        friend class List;

        ListItem* m_next;

        ListItem* m_prev;

        List* m_list;

};

class List {
    public:
        constexpr List(): m_head(nullptr), m_tail(nullptr), m_count(0) {
        }

        ~List() {
            assert(m_count == 0);
        }

        bool insertAfter(ListItem* item, ListItem* after);

        bool insertBefore(ListItem* item, ListItem* before);

        bool insertHead(ListItem* item) {
            return insertBefore(item, nullptr);
        }

        bool insertTail(ListItem* item) {
            return insertAfter(item, nullptr);
        }

        bool remove(ListItem* item) {
            if (item->m_list == this) {
                return item->remove();
            }
            return false;
        }

        ListItem* removeHead() {
            ListItem* item = m_head;
            if (item) {
                item->remove();
            }
            return item;
        }

        ListItem* removeTail() {
            ListItem* item = m_tail;
            if (item) {
                bool retval = item->remove();
                assert(retval);
            }
            return item;
        }

        ListItem* head() const {
            return m_head;
        }

        ListItem* tail() const {
            return m_tail;
        }

        unsigned int count() const {
            return m_count;
        }

        bool empty() const {
            return count() == 0;
        }

    private:
        friend class ListItem;

        ListItem* m_head;

        ListItem* m_tail;

        unsigned int m_count;

};

inline bool List::insertAfter(ListItem* item, ListItem* after) {
    assert(item != nullptr);
    if (after && (after->m_list != this)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (after) {
        item->m_prev = after;
        item->m_next = after->m_next;
        after->m_next = item;
        if (item->m_next) {
            item->m_next->m_prev = item;
        } else {
            m_tail = item;
        }
    } else {
        item->m_next = nullptr;
        item->m_prev = m_tail;
        if (item->m_prev) {
            item->m_prev->m_next = item;
        } else {
            m_head = item;
        }
        m_tail = item;
    }
    item->m_list = this;
    m_count++;
    return true;
}

inline bool List::insertBefore(ListItem* item, ListItem* before) {
    assert(item != nullptr);
    if (before && (before->m_list != this)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (before) {
        item->m_next = before;
        item->m_prev = before->m_prev;
        before->m_prev = item;
        if (item->m_prev) {
            item->m_prev->m_next = item;
        } else {
            m_head = item;
        }
    } else {
        item->m_prev = nullptr;
        item->m_next = m_head;
        if (item->m_next) {
            item->m_next->m_prev = item;
        } else {
            m_tail = item;
        }
        m_head = item;
    }
    item->m_list = this;
    m_count++;
    return true;
}

inline bool ListItem::remove() {
    List* list = m_list;
    if (list == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    if (m_next) {
        m_next->m_prev = m_prev;
    } else {
        list->m_tail = m_prev;
    }
    if (m_prev) {
        m_prev->m_next = m_next;
    } else {
        list->m_head = m_next;
    }
    list->m_count--;
    m_list = nullptr;
    return true;
}
```

Любую работу со списком произвожу только через `public` методы этих классов; перед любым вызовом метода добавления/удаления -  захватываю `pthread_mutex_t`, после вызова метода - отпускаю его.

В итоге при многопоточной работе срабатывает `assert(retval)` в методе `removeTail()` (при этом у списка `m_count` равен 1, `m_head` и `m_tail` указывают на этот элемент, а у самого элемента `m_next` и `m_prev` обнулены). То есть получается, что в списке оказывается элемент, у которого `m_list == nullptr`, хотя такого быть не должно, потому что обе функции добавления элемента присваивают ему правильное значение.

Что происходит? У меня ошибка в реализации алгоритма связанного списка (в однопоточных тестах вроде всё нормально)? Или для корректной работы недостаточного просто захватывать `pthread_mutex_t`?

Минимально рабочий пример ошибки:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
List list;

void* thread_func(void* arg) {
    ListItem item;
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        list.insertHead(&item);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[2];
    pthread_create(&threads[0], nullptr, thread_func, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], nullptr, thread_func, nullptr);
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        ListItem* item;
        do {
            item = list.removeTail();
        } while (item);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему не использовать готовые решения, базирующиеся на  ф-ции **InterlockedExchange**, **InterlockedCompareExchange**

Comment: Это WinAPI, а мне хотелось бы кроссплатформенного решения. К тому же для lock-free двусвязанного списка нужен double word CAS, который не везде поддерживается, плюс нет жёстких требований к скорости, поэтому я решил обойтись блокировками. Но почему то их не хватает...

Comment: Есть предположение, что Вы забываете где то вызвать мютекс. Например, список передается функцию, а конструктор копирования не перекрыт правильно. И все... приехали. Или, к примеру, для списка вызывается деструктор (а его не всегда можно очевидным образом завернуть в мютекс). Ну и третий вариант - для разным тредов используются *разные мютексы*. Как вариант - мютекст может быть частью класса и скрываться. Наружу будут только торчать lock/unlock.

Comment: Плюсую за ответ выше: дополните реализацию класса мьютексом.

Comment: У вас просиходит состояние гонки между потоками. Вообще все опрации со списом надо производить под защитой мютекса. Если же вы хотите создать список, который безопасен для использования во многих потоках, то рекоменду. глянуть книгу http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17636939/, в ней как раз разбирается эта проблема.

Comment: Обновил вопрос и добавил минимально рабочий пример ошибки (я знаю про RAII для mutex и т. д., я сделал код максимально простым и коротким). Как можно заметить, и insertHead, и removeTail закрыты mutex, а больше никакой работы со списком не может быть в принципе. А программа всё равно падает с assert(retval).
За книгу спасибо, я её почитаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взгляните на вот этот цикл внимательнее:

```
ListItem item;
while (true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    list.insertHead(&item);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Здесь вы добавляете в список *один и тот же элемент* много раз - и нигде в коде у вас нет защиты от подобного! Неудивительно, что все распалось.

Надо сделать следующее:

1. Добавить в методы вставки элемента assert или условный оператор, который проверит, что элемент еще не вставлен ни в один список.
2. Добавить в классы приватные конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания - чтобы никто случайно не скопировал и не присвоил, пытаясь избежать проверки из пункта 1.