# Работа со списком и запись его в файл

Tags: c++

```
Подскажите, как после загрузки списка из файла , поработать со списком(удаление, добавление элементов), загрузить список обратно в  файл с++
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    struct ListItem
    {
    int data= 0;
    ListItem* next= nullptr;
    };
    {std::ifstream fin ("list.txt",std::ifstream::app);
        ListItem*item=first;
      if (fin.is_open ())
      {
          std::cout << "File is open!!!!!!";`введите сюда код`
          while(!fin.eof())
          {
              fin.read((char*)&item->data,sizeof(item->data));
          }
          fin.close ();
      }
```

Comment: Под списком вы имеете в виду `std::set` или просто абстрактный набор данных?

Comment: Список в виде просто набора данных

Comment: SO больше подходит для конкретных вопросов. Вы уже что-то попробовали сделать? Если да, покажите код и скажите, что не так. Что не получилось?

Comment: 1) Загружаете список из файла, 2) работаете с ним, добавляете и удаляете элементы, 3) загружаете обратно в файл - как видите все просто.

Comment: {
      std::ifstream fin ("list.txt",std::ifstream::app);
        ListItem*item=first;
      if (fin.is_open ())
      {
          std::cout << "File is open!!!!!!";
          while(!fin.eof())
          {
              fin.read((char*)&item->data,sizeof(item->data));
          }
          fin.close ();
      }

Comment: список загрузила, но добавление или удаление элементов не работает

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте код туда. В комментариях он сжимается в одну строчку и выглядит не очень. И код нужен целиком, со всем необходимым. (Например, где определение `ListItem`? Инклюды тоже нужны, и т.д.)

Comment: Посмотрите пример класса 'лист',  https://rsdn.org/forum/src/2261478.1 или на этом ресурсе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559623/Многопоточная-работа-со-связанным-списком

Comment: Можете показать код, который у вас на самом деле? То, что в вопросе, явно не компилируется. Нужен ["минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример"™](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Наподобие такого наверное (правда Вам это не поможет скорее всего, написал за два часа - куча багов, разве что примерно как делать) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>


template<typename T>
class ListIterator;

template <typename T>
class List{
public:


    using iterator = ListIterator<T>;
    using const_iterator = ListIterator<T>;


    iterator begin(){
        return iterator(m_head.get());
    }
    const_iterator begin() const{
        return const_iterator(m_head.get());
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const{
        return const_iterator{m_head.get()};
    }

    iterator end(){
        return iterator(nullptr);
    }
    const_iterator end() const{
        return const_iterator(nullptr);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const{
        return const_iterator(nullptr);
    }
    List():
        m_head{},
        m_size{0}
    {}
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& list):
        m_head{},
        m_size{0}
    {
        for (const auto& e: list){
            push_front(e);
        }
    }
    List(const List& other):
        m_head{},
        m_size{0}
    {
        for (const auto& e: other){
            push_front(e);
        }
    }
    List& operator=(const List& other){
        if (this != & other){
            clear();
            for (const auto& e: other){
                push_front(other);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~List(){
        clear();
    }
    void push_front(const T& data){
        std::shared_ptr<ListItem> newItem{new ListItem(data, m_head)};
        m_head = newItem;
        ++m_size;
    }

    void clear(){
        while (!empty()){
            pop_front();
        }
    }

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, const T& value){
        std::shared_ptr<ListItem> newItem{new ListItem(value, m_head)};
        newItem->next() = pos.m_p->next();
        pos.m_p->next() = newItem;
        ++m_size;
        return iterator(newItem.get());
    }

    const T& front() const{

        if (!empty())
            return m_head->data();
        else
            return m_emptyData; // Если список пуст - вернём пустые данные
    }

    void pop_front(){
        if (empty()){
            return;
        }
        m_head = m_head->next();
        --m_size;
    }

    std::size_t size() const{
        return m_size;
    }

    bool empty() const{
        return m_size == 0;
    }

    class ListItem{
    public:
        ListItem(const T& data, std::shared_ptr<ListItem> next = nullptr):
            m_data{data},
            m_next{next}
        {}

        ListItem() = default;
        ListItem(const ListItem& other) = default;
        ListItem& operator=(const ListItem& other) = default;
        const T& data() const{
            return m_data;
        }
        T& data(){
            return m_data;
        }

        const std::shared_ptr<ListItem>& next() const{
            return m_next;
        }

        std::shared_ptr<ListItem>& next(){
            return m_next;
        }

    private:
        T m_data;
        std::shared_ptr<ListItem> m_next;
    };
private:


    std::shared_ptr<ListItem> m_head;
    std::size_t               m_size;
    static const T            m_emptyData = T();
};


template<typename T>
class ListIterator: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{

    friend class List<T>;
public:

    ListIterator(const ListIterator& it):
        m_p{it.m_p}
    {}

    typename ListIterator::reference operator* (){
        return m_p->data();
    }
    const  typename ListIterator::reference operator* () const{
        return m_p->data();
    }

    bool operator !=(const ListIterator& other) const{
        return m_p != other.m_p;
    }
    bool operator ==(const ListIterator& other) const{
        return m_p == other.m_p;
    }

    ListIterator& operator++(){
        m_p = m_p->next().get();
        return *this;
    }
    ListIterator operator++(int){
        ListIterator ret = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return ret;
    }


    typename List<T>::ListItem* m_p;

    ListIterator(typename List<T>::ListItem* p):
        m_p{p}
    {}




};

template<typename T>
void saveToFile(const List<T>& c, const std::string& fileName){
    std::ofstream f(fileName);
    for (const auto& e: c){
        f << e  << " ";
    }
    f.close();
    return;
}

template<typename T>
void readFromFile(List<T>& c, const std::string& fileName){
    std::ifstream f(fileName);
    T t;
    c.clear();
    while (f >> t){
        c.push_front(t);
    }
    f.close();
    return;
}


int main()
{

    List<int> l{1,2,3,4,5};
    for (const auto& e: l){
         std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    saveToFile(l, "out.txt");
    l.clear();
    readFromFile(l, "out.txt");
    auto it = l.cbegin();
    for (; it != l.cend(); it++){
        if (*it == 3){
            l.insert_after(it, 10);
        }
    }
    for (const auto& e: l){
         std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    saveToFile(l, "out.txt");
    List<int> newList;
    readFromFile(newList, "out.txt");
    std::cout << "after read from file" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& e: newList){
         std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 10 4 5 
after read from file
5 4 10 3 2 1
```

Comment: Всю образовательную работу мне портите. :) И не лень было 2 часа делать чужую домашку.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так я специально - вроде и ответ дал, вроде и воспользоваться им нельзя - ведь для этого понадобится объяснить преподавателю что такое итераторы (и главное, почему то как они тут реализованы - неправильно), что такое shared_ptr, почему работает цикл `for (const auto& e: list)`, почему при сохранении в файл и чтении оттуда список разворачивается, и прочее, прочее, прочее. Я если честно вообще не понимаю зачем такие вопросы на StackOverflow задавать, когда я учился я читал теорию (книжки) и всё это пытался закодить, а когда не работало сутками отлаживал. И оно того стоило.